# VirtualDub install Video Codec

Tags: video, codec, virtualdub

I spent hours to try to install xvid codec on my 32 bits version of VirtualDub

I know the excellent pages : http://granjow.net/virtualdub-tutorial-exporting.html#content

... Does not work and the list of codecs contains only one ... see image

Can you help me ?

Best regards

Pascal

[image: Video codec list have only the basic Uncompressed RGB]

Answer (score 0):

is that a fresh Windows installation? Have you installed a codec pack, like K-Lite?
https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm

In my experience, installing the codec pack made the codecs appear in VDub.
Also, if you're on a 64-bit Win and want to use 32-bit VDub, probably you'll have to install a 32-bit version of the codecs in order VDub to find them.